# Haskell, combination with repetitions + permutations

Tags: haskell

Lets say I have a list with elements, for example `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`. 
I want to create all permutations of this elements with length N.

So, for `N = 4` it will be 
`[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1],[2,1,1,1],..]` and so on.

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb _ [] = []
comb m (x:xs) = map (x:) (comb (m-1) xs) ++ comb m xs
```

Now, to get this lists first I find all combinations with repetitions for my list,
so `[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,4],[1,1,1,5],...]` and for each list I find all permutations and if permutation is not in the list I add it to the list.

```
permutations1 :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
permutations1 []   = [[]]
permutations1 list = [(x:xs) | x <- list, xs <- permutations1 $ delete1 x list]

delete1:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete1 _ [] = [] 
delete1 a (b:bc) | a == b = bc 
                 | otherwise = b : delete1 a bc
```

And that's how I get wanted answer.

I understand that it is really(really) bad, but I don't understand haskell enough to write function that will combine these functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is called **sampling with replacement**. In haskell you may utilize [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) and monadic behaviour of lists (i.e. *non-deterministic* computations)

```
\> import Control.Monad (replicateM)
\> length $ replicateM 4 [1..5]   -- should output 5^4
625
\> replicateM 4 [1..5]
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,4],[1,1,1,5],[1,1,2,1],[1,1,2,2],[1,1,2,3],[1,1,2,4],[1,1,2,5]] ....
```

If you want to have a sample of size 4 from a population of size 5 with replacement, then for each of the 4 items you have 5 choices; so you are *replicating* each of the `[1..5]` 4 times, hence `replicateM 4`.

The [`Monad` type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) (i.e. the `M` part) says that you should be able to *bind* these intermediate values together.

[The list instance of monad type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-726) models *non-determinism*. i.e it says that each item is non-deterministic but it can be one of `[1..5]` values, and to *bind* them together take an *outer product* of all the non-deterministic values; because if you have 4 items each taking 5 possible values then you have `5^4` possible final outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I know what exactly I need, so I can try to understand it and write my own implementation!